# Manga where the main character died because her fiancé killed her, but she is reborn to take revenge

Tags: story-identification, manga, young-adult

The female main lead's name is Sese. Her fiancé kills her but she is reborn. Her stepmother slow poisons her father. She gets to know that her fiancé was cheating on her with her sister and he was only with her for her property. She tells all of this to male main lead at first meet and he helps her.

That's all I remember. I read this on Webtoon around two years ago.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a novel or a manga?  When did you read it?

Comment: It's a manga. I read it on webtoon around 2 years ago

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[Tender Loving CEO](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tender-loving-ceo)***...?

> What the hell?! Sese Yan was murdered thanks to her evil step-mother and her fiancé. But guess what? She wakes up in the past, with a second chance at life, revenge… and even love! She’s got a decade's worth of knowledge (beware, crime lords!) and a newfound fighting spirit. Sese even finds unexpected help from the handsome and rich Jinchen Fu. Can Sese and Jinchen stop history from repeating itself? Will she get upgraded to the good life or will death catch up to her once again?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "Tender Loving CEO."]

This is a Chinese manhua set in the modern world.

The protagonist, Sese Yan, was burned to death in her apartment by her stepmother, Grace Gao, and her fiancé, Owen Lin, before regressing ten years into the past.

Shortly after waking up in the past, she meets James Fu, the male lead and titular CEO of the story, who becomes her ally and protector.

In chapter 9, it's revealed that Grace used slow-acting drugs to kill Sese's father.

In chapter 19, it's revealed that Owen had an affair with Grace.

You can read the full manhua at [Pocket Comics](https://www.pocketcomics.com/comic/3627).